# Error in Crystal Report Formula in window application

Tags: crystal-reports

Error in File temp_0592bd8d-2dfd-4b7c-b64e-d76ffd705741 {DAE19A7B-FA99-494F-9C0D-376C756D5097}.rpt:

Error in formula  BalanceAmount:

```
'(CDBL({@Total})-({@PayableAmount}))'
```

The string is non-numeric.

Details: errorKind

Edit-----------------------------------

Total formula:

```
{spForFeeRecipt.Fine}+cdbl({spForFeeRecipt.AdmissionFees}+{spForFeeRecipt.Total‌​Fees})
```

Payable Amount

`({spForFeeRecipt.Fine}+{spForFeeRecipt.PaidAmount}+cdbl({spForFeeRecipt.Admissi‌​`onFees}))

Comment: is that the entire formula?

Comment: yes Actually Total has ={spForFeeRecipt.Fine}+cdbl({spForFeeRecipt.AdmissionFees}+{spForFeeRecipt.TotalFees})

Comment: and Payable Amount =({spForFeeRecipt.Fine}+{spForFeeRecipt.PaidAmount}+cdbl({spForFeeRecipt.AdmissionFees}))

Answer (score 0):

your field `@Total` has some non numerics in the form of string like `10b` where you get these kind of errors.

Before checking first you need to make sure that that is total numeric in string form and then applt `cdbl` like below

```
if IsNumeric({@Total})
then (CDBL({@Total})-({@PayableAmount}))
else //your code
```

first check output of `Total` field and then apply the formula